# I need libnvidia-gl-450:i386 to be able to run steam, but I can't find it on the ubuntu repository

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, steam, cuda

I'm on 18.04 and I just installed cuda-11, which required the 450 drivers, and I was wondering why I couldn't find the i386 version of the new packages.

I am very unhappy because I can't play games on my machine on my machine. I'm missing this library: `libnvidia-gl-450:i386`

Is their any way to download this package? Or any way to be able to use both cuda-11 AND steam on my machine?

Comment: That isn't a Ubuntu package for any release, and if you look those packages aren't created by Ubuntu/Canonical being found in the 'restricted' repository, thus most probably nvidia closed-source issue.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libnvidia&searchon=names

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't really help me much here: The amd64 version of libnvidia-gl-450 exists on the main ubuntu repo (i just downloaded it) but cannot be found on Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I suspect if you `apt-cache policy` look you're getting it from elsewhere (3rd party and not Ubuntu/Canonical)

Comment: apt-cache policy sais I am getting it from: /var/lib/dpkg/status.

Comment: As I said - it's from nvidia & not Ubuntu/Canonical.   (the local /var/lib/dpkg/status is just a way of saying it's already installed)

Comment: Oh I see, ok thanks! So do you know how I can get the i386 version? It sais "Unable to locate package"

Comment: Since your comment showed the amd64 package is closed-source from nvidia, you'll have to ask them (they have the source, thus the capacity to package it..)

Comment: Ok, I guess it will be harder than I thought. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Steam 20.04 not working, while i have CUDA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271975/steam-20-04-not-working-while-i-have-cuda)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit the same issue (different scenario though, trying to install Blizzard Battle.net), and couldn't find a direct solution.

I've installed my nvidia 450 driver from here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/, and apparently it doesn't contain a variant for i386.

The alternative source of drivers is: [https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
This one has i386 version of libnvidia-gl package but only for driver version *440* (as of this post written - 4-Jul-2020).

The only solution that worked for me, is *completely remove* driver and packages related to driver version *450*, and install **nvidia-driver-440**.

Package `libnvidia-gl-440:i386` works for the same purpose for me.

Comment: update has come nvidia 450 now has i386 packages

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes libnvidia-gl-450 is provided as 64-bit only in repositories but the binary blob driver provided by nvidia contains the relevant 32-bit libraries. These can be installed manually.

Obviously, the 32-bit library files have to match the installed driver version. The appropriate files can be obtained by using the extract only option provided by the installer e.g. for 465.19.01 [get the driver](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/171980/en-us) and do ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01.run -x

The i386 library files are in a folder named "32". To install the 32-bit library manually:

```
chmod u+x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01.run
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01.run -x
cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-465.19.01
cd 32
sudo cp libEGL* libGLESv* libGLX* libnvidia-egl* libnvidia-gl* libnvidia-tls* /usr/lib32
```

There are some symlinks that should be created:

```
cd /usr/lib32
sudo ln -s libEGL_nvidia.so.465.19.01 libEGL_nvidia.so.0
sudo ln -s libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.465.19.01 libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
sudo ln -s libGLESv2_nvidia.so.465.19.01 libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
sudo ln -s libGLX_nvidia.so.465.19.01 libGLX_indirect.so.0
sudo ln -s libGLX_nvidia.so.465.19.01 libGLX_nvidia.so.0
```

You will probably need to run this for the system to detect the new libraries:

```
sudo ldconfig
```